# php rabbitmq Consumer stopped receiving messages after getting 3 messages

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a php producer, which produce message into a queue.
The consumer get 3 messages only then freez into the $queue->consume(); method.
If I run another consumer, it also get the following 3 messages only and freez.

Any idea why is that happening ?

Thanks.

Comment: It seams that I had an error in the ack, it's solved now.

Answer (score 0):

The messages are being held in memory without being acknowledged.  You need to release them by using ack, or nack.  Once this happens, you'll pull the next batch of messages.

Edit: Didn't see your comment, sorry.